# Crop image from camera(android)

Tags: android, image, crop

Sorry for my english. I want use camera and crop image. But have error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.bottom.smart.cropimage.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:87)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

line 87 its: `Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");`

I want do like this: click button, open camera, take a picture, crop this image and output crop image in mainActivity. Bellow my code

My code:

```
 private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;

    ImageView imgview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_camera);

        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());

                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

                try {

                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.toString());

                }
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() !=null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: use this `Bitmap yourImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

Comment: @kishorejethava thanks for answer, now i have `Null pointer exception` in `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();`

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458

Comment: You should move ` Bundle extras = data.getExtras();` into the if block where you check for data not being null. That may not solve your problem but you get rid of the exception.

Comment: Are you sure that `"data"` is actually the correct key?

Comment: @HermannKlecker i move `Bundle extras  = data.getExtras();` and have `NullPointerException` in `imgview.setImageBitmap(photo);`

Answer (score 0):

I have done some thing like this.

```
Bitmap cameraBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
SaveImageTask.SaveImageListener saveCameraImageListener = new SaveImageTask
                        .SaveImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(String filePath) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
                        beginCrop(uri);
                    }
                };

SaveImageTask saveTask = new SaveImageTask(saveCameraImageListener);
                saveTask.execute(cameraBitmap);

private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped" + System.currentTimeMillis
            ()));
    new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asSquare().start(this);
}
```